# How to fix this regex in order to preserve a given id order?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing

I have this large string:

```
s = '''Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083
mañanita mañana RG 0.796611
, , Fc 1
buscando buscar VMG0000 1
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
. . Fp 1

Pero pero CC 0.999764
vamos ir VMIP1P0 0.655914
a a SPS00 0.996023
lo el DA0NS0 0.457533
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
interesa interesar VMIP3S0 0.994868
LO_QUE_INTERESA_La lo_que_interesa_la NP00000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
clasificación clasificación NCFS000 1
A+ a+ NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ahorran ahorrar VMIP3P0 1
energía energía NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
si si CS 0.99954
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
no no RN 0.998134
equivoco equivocar VMIP1S0 1
. . Fp 1

Lava lavar VMIP3S0 0.397388
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
7 7 Z 1
kg kilogramo NCMN000 1
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.998134
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
le le PP3CSD00 1
veía ver VMII3S0 0.62272
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gran gran AQ0CS0 1
tambor tambor NCMS000 1
( ( Fpa 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
acero acero NCMS000 0.973481
inoxidable inoxidable AQ0CS0 1
) ) Fpt 1
y y CC 0.999962
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
error error NCFSD23 0.234930
error error VMDFG34 0.98763
consumo consumo NCMS000 0.948927
máximo máximo AQ0MS0 0.986111
de de SPS00 0.999984
49 49 Z 1
litros litro NCMP000 1
error error DI0S3DF 1
Mandos mandos NP00000 1
intuitivos intuitivo AQ0MP0 1
, , Fc 1
todo todo PI0MS000 0.43165
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
explicado explicar VMP00SM 1
, , Fc 1
jamas jamas RG 0.343443
nada nada PI0CS000 0.850279
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
de de SPS00 0.999984
nunca nunca RG 0.903
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
de de SPS00 0.999984
mis mi DP1CPS 0.995868
error error VM9032 0.234323
string string VMWEOO 0.03444
padres padre NCMP000 1
Además además NP00000 1
incluye incluir VMIP3S0 0.994868
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
tecnología tecnología NCFS000 1
error errpr RG2303 1
Textileprotec textileprotec NP00000 1
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
protege proteger VMIP3S0 0.994868
nuestras nuestro DP1FPP 0.994186
ninguna ninguno DI0S3DF 0.345344
falla falla NCFSD23 1
prendas prenda NCFP000 0.95625
más más RG 1
preciadas preciar VMP00PF 1
jamas jamas RG2303 1
string string VM9032 0.234323
nunca nunca RG 0.293030
string string VM 0.902333
no no RN
le le PP004DF 0.390230
falla fallar VM0FD00 0.99033
. . Fp 1'''
```

I would like to extract in a list the second word from left to right and its id that holds this ids pattern: `RN_ _ _ _ _`, `PP_ _ _ _ _`, `VM_ _ _ _ _`. This ids must be together. For example:

```
no no RN 0.90383
le le PPSDF23 0.902339
falla fallar VM00DKE 0.9045
```

This is the pattern I would like to match, since they are together and the ids have the `RN_ _ _ _ _`, `PP_ _ _ _ _`, `VM_ _ _ _ _` order this should be the output given the `s` string:

```
   [('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]
```

This is what I tried:

```
together__ = re.findall(r'(?s)(\w+\s+RN)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+PP\w+)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', s)
```

but I get this with the above regex:

```
print together__
```

output:

```
[('no RN', 'le PP3CSD00', 'ver VMII3S0'), ('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]
```

Which is wrong since the ids are not consecutevely in the string s (`RN, PP, VM`). How can I fix this regex?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I provide a baseline and an explanation... I dont get what is wrong.

Comment: What are the underscores?

Comment: A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is helpful because a small example is easier to read and understand. The example here is long and difficult to understand. In this case, the first 40 lines of the example string could be omitted along with lines between (I think) 70 and 110. You might also want to try [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/).

Comment: @CommuSoft the underscores are free characters (the underscores are just strings I would not want to match) thanks.

Comment: So you basically only want the word just before the `RN/PP/VM` stuff?

Comment: @CommuSoft yes, but they need to be together one followed by one in this order: `RN/PP/VM`

Comment: @newWithPython: is `ir VMM03S0` than a match?

Comment: @CommuSoft yes VMM03S0 would match but it needs to be before a PP and this PP should be before a  RN. In this order `RN` `PP` `VM`

Comment: Must you use a regex? A simple parser sounds easier to me...

Comment: @RedX For this case yes...  thanks for the feedback

Comment: @newWithPython: Please try to be more specific next time. You can perhaps use google translate for the hard parts. But without specifications, it's extremely hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry... I know that I've tried to be very specific but this is a weird problem... I'm stuck. thank you @CommuSoft I will take it in count!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better

You can do this simply with:

```
list = re.findall(r'\n?\s*\S+\s+(\w+\W+RN\w*)[^\n]*[^\n]*?\n\s*\S+\s+(\w+\W+PP\w*)[^\n]*[^\n]*?\n\s*\S+\s+(\w+\W+VM\w*)[^\n]*', s)
```

Resulting in:

```
[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]
```

because `ver VM` is first.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the order is not preserved, the right output is this: `[('no', 'RN'),('le','PP'), ('fallar', 'VM')]`

Comment: Since it preserve the `RN` `PP` `VM` order

Comment: @newWithPython: so you want to basically sort on the second tupple element?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I would like to extract in a list the second word from left to right and its id that holds this ids pattern: `RN_ _ _ _ _`,`PP_ _ _ _ _`,`VM_ _ _ _ _`, where  `_`are free characters of the id. This ids must be together. In adition I would like to return the full id

Comment: Well, the list is captured from left to right. If you look to the resulting tuples, you will see that all items are there in that order. A regex by default output from *start-to-end*. It's still unclear what you mean simply because according to your description, more strings match. The first element `('ir', 'VM')` originates for instance from the first line `Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083`

Comment: @newWithPython: finally got it I think, but the last is `ver VM` because that one comes first.

Comment: It should start at a newline?

Comment: What about this: `together__ = re.findall(r'(?s)(\w+\s+RN)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+PP\w+)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', s)` the problem is that it doesnt preserve the given order, they must ocurre one followed by one in this order: RN PP VM thanks!

Comment: So what is the number of items as output you expect? Three or a lot more? Your specs are completely unclear... Can you please explain why `ver VM` located the line after `le PP` is not valid?

Comment: this is the expected output: `[(no RN, le PP004DF, fallar VM0FD00])`. It is not the pattern i need. They are not one after another.

Comment: @newWithPython: yes I know that by now, but one needs to know the **rules** to determine why the given output is not valid. Please provide an **argument/explenation/** so one can write a pattern that omits that line...

Comment: @newWithPython: I think I finally understood: you are looking for **consecutive** (consecutivo) lines.

Comment: pretty close but I need to return the full id, like this: `[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]`

Comment: @newWithPython: final question: do lines have to start with a hash (`#`)?

Comment: no, sorry let me edit that!. This should be the right output:`[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')] `

Comment: Sure this is!. Sorry guys as I told you... this was a very weird task since I am extracting spanish patterns... sorry for the inconvenient!

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't get a decent answer soon enough, I think that I may be close to what you want with this:

```
re.findall(r'\n[^\n]*?\s(.*?\sRN[^\n]*)\n[^\n]*?\s(.*?\sPP[^\n]*)\n[^\n]*?\s(.*?\sVM[^\n]*)\n', s)
```

I don't know why I get both words in the first item... might be because of the "#" and I did not bother cutting after RN, PP and VM. I guess that if the first step works decently enough, the rest can be easily fixed in post-processing.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This is almost ok. This is the output of your regex: `[('no no RN', 'le PP004DF 0.390230', 'fallar VM0FD00 0.99033')]` the problem with this is that I would like to filter ´number´and one `no`. So the correct output should be: `[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]`

Comment: In the first item you only get one word as in the other items. I used this:`re.findall(r'(?s)(\w+\s+RN)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+PP\w+)(?:(?!\s(?:RN|PP|VM)).)*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)', s)` the thing is I would like to preserve the `RN`, `PP`, `VM` order (they must ocurre consecutevely, one followed by the other.) thanks

Comment: The reason is that your `[^\n]` is non-greedy as well, and the priority is left to right.

Comment: I see.. any idea of how to fix it @CommuSoft ? thanks!

Comment: That may be right if you're sure you're only interested in words: `re.findall(r'(\w*?\sRN[^\n]*)\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sPP[^\n]*)\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sVM[^\n]*)\n', s)` ... still some post processing left but that should be easy -_-

Comment: @etna: simply but `[^\n]*` outside the brackets.

Comment: @etna this is pretty close, this is the output: `[('no RN', 'le PP004DF 0.390230', 'fallar VM0FD00 0.99033')]`, the problem with this are the numbers, it should have no numbers, e.g. : `[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]`

Comment: CommuSoft is right... watching tv and lost track of what I did -_- Ok so `re.findall(r'(\w*?\sRN)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sPP)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sVM)[^\n]*\n', s)`

Comment: No, is not right, this is the right output:`[('no RN', 'le PP004DF', 'fallar VM0FD00')]`. This is wrong since I need to return the full id. Sorry guys!

Comment: `re.findall(r'(\w*?\sRN.*?)\s?[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sPP).*?\s[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?\s(\w*?\sVM.*?)\s[^\n]*\n', s)` Ok I'm late :)

Comment: or perhaps `\w+` inside the brackets... Anyway, the problem was merely to understand the problem I think.

Comment: Yep, I left a typo after PP and can't fix it now... anyway, problem solved :)